# Using Azure Notification Hub, who is reporting "no matching targets"?

Tags: azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending notifications to FCM, either from my Azure Service via Azure Notification Hub or it's test send, I am not getting any error messages, but the notification is not delivered to the specified device. The hub's test send reports "Message was successfully sent, but there were no matching targets."  However, from the FCM portal test send it is, so I know the device is configured correctly.

Is it FCM reporting "no matching targets" or the hub?

I have tried a variety of device ids as targets, both the token received from FCM by the device and variations of the FCM Token generated by the GetFMToken method.

Using VS, I see in the hub registrations for APNS; I don't see any for FCM, even though I have seen registration events for my pushes in the hub's Overview Monitoring.

An example of the latest notice semantics:

"{ "priority": "high", "data": { "Raw": "PIDMe*54*****64*Test190801142953088468/1/2019 2:29:53 PM"}, "notification": {"channel_id": "MyNotications"}, "to" : "f-E6xD_YkFs:APA91bEsHI_Fc9zNKFfYWm2b5-ebVuS-Kp8WLMM0YgWVv6fc6dXpqvwJGUNedE9ZfaBpiDC69IQJt4hjizm98l7Lbo3RzyeHi5dAzKnFvKNZ4nCgEIoQShEGfgB5AkhS-2j7LXtcjudC"}

I expect just ""Message was successfully sent" and the notification delivered.

Comment: It appears that the "reply" is a Hub response to the transmission result received by the Hub from FCM. I have opened a case with Firebase support to determine if the syntax of the notification is correct given the scenario.

Comment: Having connected with 3 Firebase support team members, none have been able to analyze the notice and provide suggestions. Because I used Azure in the first two support requests, they proposed that the problem was with the Notification Hub. The third just pointed me at the Firebase documentation.

Has anyone successfully composed their own notification and sent it to FCM via Azure from their own server to a targeted Android device on a channel?

Comment: Any possible solution to this problem ?

Comment: I modified the manifest to eliminate the use of keys in the <service> and <receiver> in the android.name setting from

<receiver "android:name="md50d7658ca0fc01b95086956189e698682.PushReceiver"><br>
to both

<receiver android:name=".receivers.PushReceiver">  <br>
and

<service android:name="com.identitycheckpoint.com.PushReceiver"> <br>
without success. I also searched for "org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar" and "base.apk" in the solution and couldn't find them, either in the folders or as a word phrase within the files.

Comment: Reading the error messages deeper, I notice that other classes than "com.identitycheckpoint.sentry.FirebaseService" were not found. Looking for those other classes, they were not present in the code. Thus I eliminated from the manifest the ".TokenService" service token entries and the ".PushReceiver" receiver permission entries in the manifest.

As a result the error messages at both initialization of the application and receipt of the notification have be eliminated. This problem was resolved.

Comment: It was a different issue for us altogether. We need provide at least one tag to be associated with each registration. The problems with tag was causing the "No targets found" error in Notification Hub. Nothing to do with FCM though.